# Segmented Control, present childview B from childview A

Tags: swift, segue, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm stuck on how I can show child B after a successful API call from child A. I am using a container view with embedded segues to the 2 views.

The parent view has a segment control that I'm using like this:

```
@IBAction func segmentsPressed(_ sender: AwardSegmentedControl) {
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        container.segueIdentifierReceivedFromParent("A")
    } else {
        container.segueIdentifierReceivedFromParent("B")
    }
}
```

I added a function on the parent view called changeView which I'm calling from a successful API call from A.

```
func changeSubView() {
   let oldController =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "A") as! AwardStoreVC
   oldController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
   oldController.view.removeFromSuperview()
   oldController.removeFromParentViewController()

   let controller =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "B") as! AwardsForUserVC
   addChildViewController(controller)
   view.addSubview(controller.view)

   controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

But nothing happens. Is this the right approach?

Comment: In your code, `oldController` is actually a new controller that you just created.  Its view has no superview and it has no parent.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha yes it is getting called. Phillip I just threw that in right now as a hail mary ;-/